# Scheduled Ringer Volume Change for Work Hours

Tags: iphone, ios

Can I schedule the ringer volume to drop during work hours and then go back up at the end of work?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use "**Do not disturb**":

- Go to Settings > Do Not Disturb
- Enable "Scheduled"
- Set your desired schedule

Your phone will be muted as long as you are within the DND schedule.

To see how exactly this feature works you may have a look at [Apple's explanation for Do Not Disturb](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204321).

Comment: This will silence the ringer, though, not reduce the volume as the OP requested.

Comment: Isn't "dropping the ringer volume" the same as "muting the phone"?

Comment: Not to me, but perhaps the OP can clarify.